# Precompile React with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'd like to pre-compile a React component, using [ReactDOMServer.renderToString](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring), and inject it into my [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) using Webpack. I want to do this ahead-of-time. It should compile as a static HTML file. I don't have a node.js server in my production environment to do server-side rendering.

In other words, say I have the following:

```js
// render.js
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';

export renderToString(<MyComponent />);
```

and I have the following html-webpack-plugin template:

```html
<!-- index.ejs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main id="root"></main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to inject the result from `render.js` into the "root" element in `index.ejs`?

I've tried some obvious things, such as `<%= require('render.js') %>`, but this will never work since it is lacking the entire React dev environment.

The html-webpack-plugin makes mention of a "compilation object" that is available in the EJS template, but I have not found any documentation on how to use it, so I can't tell if that is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "simple" `<%= require('render.js') %>` DOES in fact work. What I encountered was [another bug](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/73) that made me think it didn't.

So it is totally possible to pre-compile a React component with Webpack. (Just don't expect it to work with mini-css-extract-plugin until they fix the bug.)